# Ionic framework - /audio dir is skipped and not present in the build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I working on a ionic/cordova app and there is a folder called `/audio` containing mp3 files:

```
/www
 /assets
   /audio
     file.mp3
   /css
   /js
 config.xml
 index.html
```

The problem is that /audio dir is not in the build, inspecting the app folder with USB cable on android i see this:

[image]

As you can see `/css` and `/js` are ok there, just missing `/audio` dir

Why this?

Comment: In audio folder you are uploading a video file or .mp3 file

Comment: mp3 sorry just updated question

Comment: write your mp3 file path as var musicFile = $ionicPlatform.is('android') ?  '/android_asset/www/audio' : 'audio';

Comment: And after that before ionic run android , execute ionic prepare android

Comment: i don't understand why i can't simply use that dir .... is there some default "skipping" when building the android app?

Comment: android_assets/ does not contain /audio dir if you read my question deeply

Comment: Android file system path is different , and it will is able to find the mp3 file path ... that's why we are giving the location of mp3 file as per android file system rule's

Comment: if you run the command ionic prepare android it  will built that directory

Comment: Doesn't work , the dir is skipped yet

Comment: Can you put your code in github or plnkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fixed that.

It's quite strange, but probably assets/audio is going to be conflict with some kind of native/cordova own dir so i just renamed the dir and now everything is ok.

instead of `assets/audio` i used `assets/sound`